# Div Scaling in Multi-Level Dropdown

Tags: html, css

i am trying to scale a div Container in a dropdown menu, so that it fits the text inside better.

```
<div class='dropdown'>
    <button class ="dropbtn"><b>Hover!</b></button>
    <div class='dropdown-content'>
        <div class='dropdown-level2'>
            <button class ="dropbtn-level2"><b>"..."</b></button>
            <div class='dropdown-content-level2'>
                <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLvxwY

Of course i could just set a min-width, however the content is dynamically generated. Thus a text shorter than the min-width can occur.

How can i scale the div accordingly?

Thanks

Comment: You mean to change container width by text long?

Comment: By text length, yes.

Comment: Sadly it did not. I tried testing it in the codepen. But the results where not as desired.

Comment: What is the desired outcome for you?

Comment: look this code pen http://codepen.io/Wolka/pen/VKqoXm. I'm edit my answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I made a mistake. This works!

Comment: No problem, you can use it however you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Js and count your text length.

After that change the container width with `If, Else if and Else` statement.

**Its look like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.dropdown-content-level2 > a').each(function(){

    //count your text length
    var textLength = $(this).html().length;

    //if it less from 100 characters
    if (textLength < 100) {

      $(this).css('width', '100px')

    } else {

      $(this).css('width', '200px')

    }

  })

})
```

**And if you have more situations:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.dropdown-content-level2 > a').each(function(){

    var textLength = $(this).html().length;

    if (textLength < 100) {

      $(this).css('width', '100px')

    } else if (textLength > 100 && textLength < 200) {

      $(this).css('width', '200px')

    } else {

      $(this).css('width', '300px')

    }

  })

})
```

Working [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Wolka/pen/VKqoXm)